# How can I install a recent version of php?

Tags: php, symfony, version, php-7.2, php-7.3

I have a problem with a Symfony project that I have to work on, when I try a '*composer install*' on my bash, I have this message :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.5.1].
    - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - ocramius/package-versions 1.5.1 requires php ^7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.3 requires ocramius/package-versions ^1.1.3 -> satisfiable by ocramius/package-versions[1.5.1].
    - Installation request for ocramius/proxy-manager 2.2.3 -> satisfiable by ocramius/proxy-manager[2.2.3].
```

It seems obvious that my php version isn't up-to-date and I have to upgrade to the 7.3.0 version minimum, but when I make an 'apt search php', the latest version that I have is 7.2 and the '*php -v*' command return this message :

```
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3 (cli) (built: Feb 11 2020 15:55:52) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Did anyone how can I force the upgrade of my php version ? It will be very helpfull.

Thanks & have a great day

Comment: Did you try `apt update` to update list of dependencies ? Then run ` apt search php`.

Comment: Yes, after running this command it tell me that I installed the latest version of php is already installed, like if it can't find 7.3 or 7.4

Comment: What is the os version ?

Comment: I have a Linux Mint 19.3

Comment: Did you have the right  repository  ? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: I don't know, where can  verify this ? In the composer.json ?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge by the way, all of this is new to me

Comment: You could list all repositories with `ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Then you should see a file like `ondrej-*-php-focal.list` in the list. If not, add the repository and redo the `apt-get update`.

Comment: It work's ! I think I will be able to continue myself from now. Thank you mate ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your PHP version, depending of your OS but you can also "fix" the PHP version in your project with `composer.json`. In your composer.json you may have a "config" key, add "platform" with your PHP version, 7.2 in your case:

```
{
    "name": "xxxx",
    ...
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.3"
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

It's recommended to fix the version that you have in production :

- Official doc: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform
- Check also this blog article : https://blog.martinhujer.cz/17-tips-for-using-composer-efficiently/ ([Tip #15](https://blog.martinhujer.cz/17-tips-for-using-composer-efficiently/#tip-%2315%3A-specify-the-production-php-version-in-%60composer.json%60))

To update PHP version to 7.3 on linux, here is steps :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install php7.3
```

If you need to install additional packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.3-{bcmath,bz2,intl,gd,mbstring,mysql,zip}
```